# Cannot convert String Type 'String' to 'MVCTutorial.Model.tblDept'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show list of employees to view by following code. I have `tblemployee` class and `tblDept` class.

```
EmployeeViewModel EmployeeVM = new EmployeeViewModel();
MvcEmployeeEntities db = new MvcEmployeeEntities();
List<TblEmployee> emplist = db.TblEmployees.ToList();

        List<EmployeeViewModel> EmpVMlist = emplist.Select(
            x => new EmployeeViewModel { 
                Emp_ID = x.Emp_ID, 
                Emp_Name = x.Emp_Name, 
                Emp_Number = x.Emp_Number, 
                DeptID = x.DeptID, 
              **DeptName = x.tblDept.DeptName** }).ToList();

Return(EmpVMlist);
```

at this point deptName shows error saying String can't be implicitly converted to **NamespaceModel** Class.

Is they any way to implicitly convert it ?

*Note I have a `Public virtual tblDept  deptName {get;set;}`* as it is driven from `tbldept`.class

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Emp_Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeptID { get; set; }
    //virtual to use an other tble with in this tble, to get set there tblValues
    public virtual tblDept DeptName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And `MvcEmployeeEntities.tblDept.DeptName` is obviously a string. That's what the error says - you tried to set a string value into a `tblDept` property

Comment: Well, what is a `tblDept`?  Why *should* it be convertible to/from a string?  Or have you incorrectly built your models?  You seem to be mixing up a "Table Department" (?) and a "Department Name" (?), which intuitively sound to be two different things.

Comment: i have a table of employee & department (tblDept) and generated it from .edmx . also In my EmployeeViewModel i am fetching deptName by virtual property

Comment: @HarisRehman: So as yourself this... `public virtual tblDept DeptName { get; set; }` - Does this property represent a "Department", or a "Department Name"?  Those are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory.`x.tblDept.DeptName` in your LINQ `Select` expression will read the `DeptName` property value of the associated `Department` of the `Employee` record you are reading, but you are trying to set the property value to `DeptName` property which is of type `tblDept`! So basically you are trying to assign apple type to orange!

Ideally, your view model should not be using your entity classes. **View models are models specific to a view**. Keep it simple and lean. Most of the time simple-lean-flat view models are what you need.

So change your DeptName property in your view model to string.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public int? Emp_Number { get; set; }
    public int? DeptID { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}
```

Keep only those properties you absolutely need in the view, in your view model. No need to copy the entire entity class structure.